# Messy and wrong char visualization (after passing actual parameters) C++

Tags: c++, char, stack

this is my first post. Below the code of my implementation of a char Stack. Theoretically It should print f,g,h. But when I execute it, I can just see a long list of strange signs in the console. Is a compiler issue or code issue? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int max_L = 10;
class Stack {
protected:
    char array[];
int length;
public:
    Stack(){length = 0;}
    bool push(char c) {
        if(length < max_L){
            array[length] = c;
            length++;
            return(true);
        }
        else return(false);
    }
    void pop(){
        if(length >= 1){
            cout << array[length];
            length--;
        } else return ;
    }
    bool is_empty(){
        return(length == 0);
    }
    void print(){
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            cout << array[i];
        }
    }

 };

 int main() {
    Stack p1;
    p1.push('f');
    p1.push('g');
    p1.push('h');`
    p1.print();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It's almost never anything outside of your own code.

Comment: `char array[];` should probably be `char array[max_L ];`

Comment: Thanks  πάντα ῥεῖ it was definitely that the problem. Can you explain me why?

Comment: If you're asking whether it's a compiler issue, it never is. If you had genuine reasons to suspect a compiler bug, you would have written a systematic set of tests and cross-checked it on other compilers to be confident.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kerrek SB

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code. As πάντα ῥεῖ said, the array has to be created with a size. The other problem is that `push` and `pop` aren't quite complementary. `push` puts the added value at `array[length]`, then increments `length`. So after a call to `push`, `length` is the index of the **next** entry, i.e., the one that hasn't been put in yet. `pop` has to look at the **previous** entry, i.e., the one that was just put in. So the code for `pop` should decrement `length` **before** looking at `array[length]`. Change

```
cout << array[length];
length--;
```

to

```
length--;
cout << array[length];
```

Comment: Perfect. I corrected it with cout << array[length-1] but inverting the two instructions if fairly better. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeDi - yes, `array[length - 1]` also avoids the problem, and for something as simple as this it's okay. In general, decrementing first is better, because it reduces the risk of forgetting to subtract 1, and emphasizes the symmetry of the two functions.

Comment: ..... Pete Becker if I decrement with length--; and then I print the length indexed value with cout << array[length];  yes I print the value that I want to remove but  I don't update length value with an assignment. So, length variable (which should tell me till which point my array is full) tell me that I didn't removed my element.

Comment: @MikeDi - `length--;` has the same effect as `length = length - 1;`.

Comment: So I think it should be cout << array[length - 1]; length--; (two decrement, one to print the right element one to update the new fillness status) that is different from length--; cout << array[length]; (which just print the right element). IMHO.